# Fan control in Ubuntu 14.10. on Asus z97

Tags: overheating, fan, temperature

How to properly set up fan control on Ubuntu 14.10? I have an Asus z97 mini motherboard and while in windows even with heavy load for a long time it does not reach 70 Celsius degree, on Ubuntu easily reach 80 degrees in a few seconds with heavy workload.

I have read that thermald can help to motorize fan control, but I cannot find too much documentation.

Does someone know how can I make the fan to work earlier, so the computer does not reach those high temperatures?

Thanks!
D.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, [Thermald](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/PowerManagement/ThermalIssues) is the software you need and detailed instructions are available at the official Ubuntu site.

It's as easy as

```
sudo apt-get install thermald
```

on most machines.

How I use thermald is in sem-automatic mode: I have 2 /etc/thermald/thermald.conf files and when I need to extend my battery -life, I copy thermald.conf.quiet over the existing file or when performance is needed thermald.conf.performance gets copied over...

This is just one little part of a script that uses pm-powersave, gsettings, ... to regulate my performance settings. (Also, my on-board NVidia is always disabled unless I need it to do heavy-duty gaming or drive my HDMI port.)

If you're freaked out about your T°, you want even more finely tuned control and then you need the `lm-sensor` package which I did fine-tune on 12.04 but whose fine-tuning I lost when my upgrade from 12.04->14.04 crashed my system.  (I have it installed but not fine-tuned yet) so if you want to go down this road, drop me a note.

Comment: Thanks Fabby.

Thermald looks promising, but actually I think the instructions are far from being detailed. They are just a brief description of thermald and a link to the thermald-conf.xml file to configure the service, which lacks of a precise explanation of every configuration option. 

Moreover, being this a sensible topic, which is not really well addressed so far in Linux, or at least not automatically, it should be explained with more detail. I need Linux to do intensive tasks, when I see the processor running over 80º for longer than 10 minutes makes me suffer!!!!